# copy all files that have no extension

Tags: shell, filenames, wildcards, cp

We can copy some file by extensions like this:

```
cp *.txt ../new/
```

but how can I copy all files that have no extension?

Comment: What other things do the files have in common besides having no extension?

Comment: Nothing. for example files are like this : `a`, `a.txt`, `b`, `b.txt` ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer from @ubaid-ashraf is almost there. The way to specify file with no extension, in `ksh` would be:

```
cp -- !(*.*) /new/path/
```

so that any file with dot in file name is skipped.

For that to work in `bash`, you need to enable the `extglob` option (`shopt -s extglob`) and the `kshglob` option in `zsh` (`set -o kshglob`).

Comment: the problem with this  (and @ubaid-ashraf 's solution) is that it will also move directories , since most directories will not have any extensions.  My solution would ensure that there are no directories moved

Comment: No it would not move directories. `cp` would skip directories unless used with `-r` or `-R` option.

Comment: And what if I have a file called `my.file.txt`?

Comment: The pattern `*.*` matches `my.file.txt`, so presumably the file would not be copied.

Comment: why do you use `--` after cp? i do that without `--` and it works. btw, what is usage of `--`?

Comment: @hoosssein Double dash prevents anything that follows to be treated as command line options. If there are odd file names like "-r" or "-s", double dash can help guarding against potential disaster.

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like:

```
cp -- !(*.txt) /path/to/directory
```

The above code will copy all the files without .txt extension. You can also give multiple extension via pipe character.

For example:

```
cp -- !(*.txt|*.c|*.py) /path/to/directory
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use find+grep to get only files that have no extension

```
   find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sed 's/^\.\///' | grep -v "\."
```

So your copy command will be

```
   cp ` find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sed 's/^\.\///' | grep -v "\." ` destination_folder
```